# Android calender with events

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

I have been trying to implement calendar view with showing events for dates as shown in following image:(Events shown as green dots below image)

[image]

I have looked for android calendar view but found that its not supported with that as it is just a widget.

Then I got to know that there are various plugins to implements such functionality. So question is which one is good for my aim?

Comment: Hey dude .. You done this ?

Comment: Yes, Implemented this with Recycler View.

Comment: can u please post the code . I do need this one.